# Azure Bot service for Yammer Channel

Tags: botframework, bots, yammer, azure-bot-service

I looking for the way to create a bot service for Yammer channel, but this channel isn't available, and you can't read or write on this application.
I found some pieces of information about AtBot logic, or the integration of Yammer in Teams, but these topics Don't respond to my need.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

You would have to build what we refer to as a "connector" in bot framework.  This would translate from what the [Yammer Rest API](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/rest-api-rate-limits) is expecting to receive/send to/from  [Activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) which is what the bot framework SDK expects.  There is a lot more to this than that once you add in rich content and other channel specific features, but that is the general idea.

Comment: Hi @JasonSowers, 

Thank you a lot for your feedback! So if i resume, for my understanding, i need to create a "connector" like Connector channels in Azure for Teams or Skype. And for this use the Yammer REST API and activities bot builder to create an interaction between Yammer and my bot ?!

Regards,

Comment: Yes, like I said you need to build something that will translate what the yammer API  expects to receive or returns in a request or response into what the Bot Framework SDK expects.  It is going to be a fairly large amount of work depending on what features Yammer has and what all you want to use.